# Using specific strings from text files for comparison to user input

Tags: c

I need your help. I've been stuck on this problem for hours and can't find an answer that can help me. I have been trying to use fgets to lift a specific string from a text file, so I can compare it with a user input. But apparently the code configuration ive been using lifts the entire text file's contents. I only need one string I can compare to the user input using stricmp. Thanks!

The purpose of this code is to identify if a user typed username already exists from within a .txt database.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>

FILE *myFile;
int main()
{
        FILE *ptr_file;
        char userName[31];
        char userNameDatabase[31];



        printf("Please enter your username: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(userName); //user input



        ptr_file = fopen("MainDatabase.txt","rt"); //the filename
        if (!ptr_file)
        {
        return 1;
        printf("\nWARNING, MAIN DATABASE FILE MISSING");
        }
        while (fgets(userNameDatabase,sizeof(userNameDatabase), ptr_file))
        {

            if (stricmp(userName,userNameDatabase)== 0)
            {
            printf("\n\nYES!!!"); // For testing to see if my code can get into this part
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully at what gets() and fgets() are going to return... it will be more than just the visible characters. i.e.

> The fgets function reads a string from the input stream argument and
>   stores it in str. fgets reads characters from the current stream
>   position to and **including the first newline character**

so you may be comparing "fred\n" with "fred\r\n"